# Symfony2: why bundle not in vendor directory (FOSBundle for example)?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm creating an webapp (from zero with "symfony new web 2.8") with symfony2 and I have run this code:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0@dev"
```

Now, I'm expecting that under `vendor/` directory I will find "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" directory but this is not what happens. The directory is not present and If I search for it in all of my HD I can found it in `/usr/local/share/friendsofsymfony/`.

But Obviously this not correct because if I run

```
composer update
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle' not found in /MYPATH/app/AppKernel.php on line 19
```

So, why my bundle is not in vendor/ directory ?

How can I fix it ?

I'm on OSX.

Comment: did you run the `composer require` command in the same directory as your symfony installation's `composer.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

Really strange.

Try to set the vendor directory in your composer.json:

```
{
    // ...
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "vendor"
    }
}
```

Maybe this parameter is already set and misconfigured, locally or globally.

Comment: Hi, I have found the solution: in my ~/.composer/ there was a config file that setted /usr/local/share for the default "vendor" directory. I don't remember when or for what I have writed it, but I have delete it and all now work. And thanks to  @chalasr for the reply.